# Why does my ORDER BY sort two tables before the EXCEPT (slow) and not after (fast)?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

**SQL server 2008 R2 query optimizer puzzle**

We have two tables, both containing 9 million rows. 70.000 rows are different, the others are the same.

This is fast, 13 seconds,

```
select * from bigtable1
except select * from similar_bigtable2
```

This sorts the output and is also fast, 13 seconds as well,

```
select * into #q from bigtable1
except select * from similar_bigtable2
select * from #q order by sort_column
```

While this is enormously slow:

```
;with q as (
    select * from bigtable1
    except select * from similar_bigtable2
)
select * from q order by sort_column
```

And even a "trick" that I sometimes use to hint SQL Server that it needs to precalculate a certain part of the query before it moves on, doesn't work and results in slow query as well:

```
;with q as (
    select top 100 percent * from bigtable1
    except select * from similar_bigtable2
)
select * from q order by sort_column
```

Looking at the query plans the reason is not hard to find:

[image: Query plan]
[image: Query plan with ORDER BY]

SQL Server places two sorts of 9 million rows *before* the hashmatch, while I would prefer it to have added only one sort of 70.000 rows *after* the hashmatch.

So the question: how can I instruct the query optimizer to do that?

Comment: It does not sort before the hashmatch, it sorts and then does a merge-join (not a hash-join). Maybe there is a hint to force a hash-join (or prevent a merge-join)?

Comment: It seems that the SQL Server query optimizer determined that **sorting** the data was beneficial so it could use the much faster **Merge Join** (which only works for sorted data) instead of the much slower Hash Match Join or Nested Loop Join ....

Comment: Have you tried alternatives to `EXCEPT` (e.g. `OUTER JOIN`)? I realize the syntax is less convenient but you may be able to play with index/join hints better there (or you may not need to). The alternative you're using now (stuff into a #temp table first) is a last resort workaround but in some cases is the only way to force the optimizer to completely separate two parts of a query in a way that you want.

Answer (score 1):

The main difference between these two query plans is in fact in the difference of Hash  Match and Merge Join. Hash Match is more efficient and as you can see the query runs faster in option 1 (not using CTE).

CTE is a great tool, but it seems to be not efficient in two cases,Complex Predicates or Non-Unique Parent/Child Key. In your case there is no unique key and SQL server has to sort the data sets first to be able to fulfill your requirement.
Have a look at [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/sqlcat/optimize-recursive-cte-query) which tells you more on this issue.

So it seems either you have to accept its slowness or rewrite the logic with a WHILE loop which can be more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, any better?

```
select * from
(
    select * from bigtable1
    except 
    select * from similar_bigtable2
) t
order by sort_column
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an ideal solution but if you aren't able to structure the tsql to generate an efficient plan you could set a plan guide to force the plan you want.  Doing this would mean that if a more efficient plan becomes available SQL won't consider it but it is an option.